# JSReact, Deleting any dynamically added form content other than last item wipes the form

Tags: reactjs, dynamic-forms, dynamicform

I'm building a form with dynamically added fields and am working on the ability to delete fields if a user changes their mind about one. When deleting the last item added it works as expected, but if I have, for example, 3 dynamically added fields and delete the 2nd one, it will momentarily work and then wipe the whole form clean. Does anyone know why this might be happening?

[Codesandbox link here](https://codesandbox.io/s/reverent-payne-eyz6l), but I'm including (what I think is) all the relevant code below:

From "form.js":

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import CreditInputs from "./CreditInputs";

...


// Create an array that is all current credits except the one being deleted, set credit state to reflect new list
    const handleDeleteCredit = (e) => {
    const updatedCredits = [...creditState];
    updatedCredits.splice(parseInt(e.target.dataset.idx), 1)
    setCreditState(updatedCredits);
}

return (
    <form>            
        <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>   
        <input type="text" name="title" id="title" value={productionState.title} onChange={handleProductionChange} /> 
        <label htmlFor="production_note">Production Note</label> 
        <input type="textarea" name="production_note" id="production_note" value={productionState.production_note} onChange={handleProductionChange} />
        {
            creditState.map((val, idx) => (
                    <CreditInputs
                        key={`credit-${idx}`}
                        idx={idx}
                        creditState={creditState}
                        handleCreditChange={handleCreditChange}
                        // Pass each credit the handleDeleteCredit function
                        handleDeleteCredit={handleDeleteCredit}
                    />
            ))   
        }
        <input type="button" value="Add New Credit" onClick={addCredit}/>       
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />        
    </form>
)
}

export default Form;
```

and from "CreditInputs.js":

```
import React from "react";
import PropTypes from "prop-types";

// Take in the handleDeleteCredit function
    const CreditInputs = ({
        idx,
        creditState,
        handleCreditChange,
        handleDeleteCredit
     }) => {
    const creditId = `name-${idx}`;
    const roleId = `role-${idx}`;
    const bioId = `bio-${idx}`;

    return (
       <div key={`credit-${idx}`}>
       <label htmlFor={creditId}>{`Credit #${idx + 1} Name`}</label>
       
       ...

       {/* Make Delete Button */}
       <button data-idx={idx} onClick={handleDeleteCredit}>Delete Credit</button>
       </div>
     );
     };

     CreditInputs.propTypes = {
       idx: PropTypes.number,
       creditState: PropTypes.array,
       handleCreditChange: PropTypes.func,
       //   Assign handleDeleteCredit a PropType
       handleDeleteCredit: PropTypes.func
     };

     export default CreditInputs;
```

Any ideas would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must call `e.preventDefault()` at the top of `handleDeleteCredit`.  The problem was default form behavior and the result was the entire page reloading fresh.

```
 const handleDeleteCredit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    const updatedCredits = [...creditState];
    updatedCredits.splice(parseInt(e.target.dataset.idx), 1)
    setCreditState(updatedCredits);
}
```

Comment: Interesting, I've only ever had to use e.preventDefault on submit buttons before... I was confused because it was working as expected when I deleted only the last item, but I guess that doesn't trigger a reindexing of the items (and hence a refresh). Anyhow, thanks for your feedback, it's working now!